# Django receive multiple files upload

Tags: python, django

```
<input type='file' name="images[]" />

files = request.FILES['images']
print(files[0].name)
```

I have trouble to get multiple files upload in Django 3.0

Can anyone tell me why I got MultiValueDictKeyError

Comment: You might want to default to empty list by using `get` such as, `files = request.FILES.get('images', [])`

Comment: use django filer library https://github.com/E-RROR/djfiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('images[]')
print(files[1].name)
```

after many tries, I finally get correct one, use `getlist('images[]')` will works